# Rails Nested Resources - Many Objects, Same Model, One Form Without Existing Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, resources, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a model Vendors which has many Products. I would like to add many Products at a time without showing the existing products that belong to the vendor.product relationship. I only want to display the form for new objects. Currently everything is working but on the add page I am getting all of the objects that are tied to the instance relationship which is @vendor.products. If I do not use that relationship in the form I do not get any fields.

Here is my new Product action:

```
'def new
    @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
    5.times {@vendor.products.build}

  end'
```

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for @vendor do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :products do |g| %>
    <p>
     <%= g.label :name %>
     <%= g.text_field :name %>
     <%= g.label :category %>
     <%= g.select :category, options_for_select(['Parts', 'Labor', 'Extras', 'Shop']) %><br>
    </p>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

The Product Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendors
  attr_accessible :name, :category, :vendor_id, :vendor_sku, :products
  validates :name, :uniqueness => true
  validates :category, :presence => true
  validates :name, :presence =>true
end
```

Just to reiterate, I would only like to show the blank, newly built objects as opposed to all of the products tied to that @vendor 's relationship. I must be overlooking a form structure to get this done but I just have not been able to figure it out. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only render the nested fields if the product in a new record.

```
<%= form_for @vendor do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :products do |g| %>
    <% if g.object.new_record? %>
      <p>
       <%= g.label :name %>
       <%= g.text_field :name %>
       <%= g.label :category %>
       <%= g.select :category, options_for_select(['Parts', 'Labor', 'Extras', 'Shop']) %><br>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of the new_record method.